# Execute Commands After Main Process (php-fpm) has started in Docker

Tags: php, shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using docker swarm for my laravel application.
i have a service called `app` extending [official php image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and contains my main application source code plus php-fpm and can be scaled when needed.

i want to run a set of shell commands everytime a container is created and some of commands (e.g: pre-complice opcache into the memory) MUST be executed after php-fpm process  has started.

actually i have managed to make something that works but feels naive to me and the php-fpm PID is not 1

im using this code in containers entrypoint :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -m
exec php-fpm &
#
#commands goes here
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache 
#compile opcache
SCRIPT_NAME=/opcache-api/compile \
REQUEST_URI=/opcache-api/compile \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/html/public/index.php \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1 \
QUERY_STRING=force=true \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
#here i bring the process to foreground
fg 1
```

so is there a better a way to achieve this ? and make process PID 1 so docker can correctly send signals to it?

Comment: hy not to add `CMD` to  `php-fpm` , it should works

Comment: @LinPy i have like 4 commands needs to be run and one the must be passed through cgi-fcgi command to the running php-fpm,i edited my question to include my commands